# Begginer in Python - RNA transcript for a list of DNA sequences

Tags: python, list

I'm quite new to Python, and I'm trying to get the RNA transcription of a DNA sequence. Although I was able to do this for a single DNA sequence, I'm trying to find a way to do it for a list of DNA sequences. I hope you can please give me some guidance.

```
# Given this DNA sequence, get the RNA sequence:
dna = 'ACCTGACT'

# Defining the RNA transcription formula
def to_rna(dna_strand):
    mapping = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'A':'U'}
    rna_strand = ''
    for char in dna_strand:
        rna_strand += mapping[char]
    return rna_strand
```

Output:

```
RNA transcript= UGGACUGA
```

What I have been trying to do, is to get a list of RNA transcription from a list of DNA sequences. I tried already to modify the code above, but I couldn't achieve any solution. I wonder if you could please help me with this question.

Input would be:

```
dna1= ['ACCTGACT','AATTGTCT']
```

Expected outcome:

```
rna1 = ['UGGACUGA','UUAACAGA']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`List Comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
In [623]: def to_rna(dna_strand):
     ...:     mapping = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'A':'U'}
     ...:     rna_strand = ''
     ...:     for char in dna_strand:
     ...:         rna_strand += mapping[char]
     ...:     return rna_strand
     ...: 

In [626]: rna1 = [to_rna(i) for i in dna1]

In [627]: rna1
Out[627]: ['UGGACUGA', 'UUAACAGA']
```

The above is equivalent to a [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) loop:

```
In [630]: rna1 = []

In [631]: for i in dna1:
     ...:     rna1.append(to_rna(i))
     ...: 

In [632]: rna1
Out[632]: ['UGGACUGA', 'UUAACAGA']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was more simple than I thought. I was trying to modify my initial code. This is really helpful, I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 mapping = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'A':'U'}
 dna1= ['ACCTGACT','AATTGTCT']

rna_word_list = [
    "".join((mapping[dna_char] for dna_char in dna_word))
    for dna_word in dna1
]

print(rna_word_list)
```

```
['UGGACUGA', 'UUAACAGA']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example for the map function. ‚map‘ takes a function f and a list l and applies f to each element of l. In your case that’d be

```
dnas = ['ACCTGACT' , 'ATTA']

mapping = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'A':'U'}

def to_rna(dna):
        return ''.join(map(lambda x: mapping[x], dna))
        
rnas = list(map(to_rna, dnas))
print(rnas)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin `translate` with integer keys, which is **much much faster (40 times) than your custom method** and other answers

```
table = {71: 67, 67: 71, 84: 65, 65: 85}
dna = 'ACCTGACT'
assert dna.translate(table) == 'UGGACUGA'
```

e.g. with:

```
$ python -m timeit "table = <table>; x = 'gctaatcg'*N" '<method>'
```

where

```
JOIN_MAP =>
  table = None
  method = "".join(table[c] for c in x)
TRLT_STR =>
  table = {'g': 'c', 'c': 'g', 't': 'a', 'a': 'u'}
  method = x.translate(table)
TRLT_ORD =>
  table = {ord('g'): ord('c'), ord('c'): ord('g'), ord('t'): ord('a'), ord('a'): ord('u')}
  method = x.translate(table)
```

Running the above with `Python 3.9.0` on a recent MacBook:

```
N = 1000
TRLT_ORD  20000 loops, best of 5: 10.3 usec per loop
TRLT_STR  500 loops, best of 5: 394 usec per loop
JOIN_MAP  500 loops, best of 5: 401 usec per loop
```

e.g. fastest version:

```
$ python -m timeit "table = {ord('g'): ord('c'), ord('c'): ord('g'), ord('t'): ord('a'), ord('a'): ord('u')}; x = 'gctaatcg'*1000" 'x.translate(table)'
```

Note for small numbers it won't matter as much

```
N = 1
TRLT_STR  500000 loops, best of 5: 406 nsec per loop
TRLT_ORD  500000 loops, best of 5: 641 nsec per loop
JOIN_MAP  500000 loops, best of 5: 931 nsec per loop
```